# How to wrap node express output so that it can be included as javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, include

Trying to modify node.js express to wrap the standard output in javascript (utilising document.write) so that I can include it into other HTML files. I want to encode the output at the express level and decode it at the client.

Edit: I want to create a standard node app that generates HTML output but wrap it just before sending with the javascript. This is so I can continue to utilise express-handlebars and other add ons without disruption to the output.

If this is already a thing in node please point me to documentation on how to achieve it? Otherwise I'm looking for where to change the code in express to wrap each output.

For clarity; to answer please include a reference the correct express file(s) and start with existing code to produce a modified version that achieves my goal.

The Express version I am looking at is 4.15.4. I've viewed the code and found the index.js and route.js files (https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/lib/router) but don't understand enough to know where to modify the code.

**Example**

My initial goal would be for my node app to return encoded HTML wrapped in code similar to the following:

```
var str = "<encoded content goes here>";
document.write(decodeURI(str));
```

Example way to call my node from HTML:

```
<script src='http://localhost:3000/'></script>
```

---

Feel free to comment on the approach if you have an opinion.

Thanks!

Comment: You would just return it in your get handler.. eg..  `app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.end("<encoded content goes here>"); })`

Comment: So maybe I am getting confused because I am also using express-handlebars. router.get('/js', function(req, res){
 var str = "<div>This is a test</div>";
 res.render('jsinclude', { content: str, layout: false});
});

Comment: @keith While that would work I realise what I want to do is generate a standard node app that returns HTML but at the very last wraps it with this javascript. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out.

In file https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js @ line 116 I added the following code:

```
  chunk = "str = \""+encodeURI(body)+"\";\ndocument.write(decodeURI(str));\n";
```

Seems to have worked.

So:

```
res.send = function send(body) {
  var chunk = body;
  var encoding;
  var len;
  var req = this.req;
  var type;

  // settings
  var app = this.app;
<added my code here>
  // allow status / body
```